# ORA-00060 trace file explanation

Tags: oracle, database-deadlocks

I have this well known deadlock in a merging query. There is no foreign keys, triggers, any PL/SQL. The master table is btree index only with a composite primary key. The helper table is temporal session private (no even a primary key).
Multiple threads inserts entries into the temporal table and call merge.

All this stuff looks pretty typical but I cannot classify the problem source. I dug up an article doing this [Application design is only reason for](http://arup.blogspot.ru/2013/04/application-design-is-only-reason-for.html). My case doesn't fit any of mentioned patterns %100.

Lock types in the deadlock graph looks like "primary key overlap", but my trace has rows. Though there are 2 looping rows but the contingent case has no rows at all.

```
Deadlock graph:
                       ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TX-0006000d-00010e04        24    1432     X             23    2918           S
TX-00270002-00019175        23    2918     X             24    1432           S

session 1432: DID 0001-0017-015A7B2A    session 2918: DID 0001-0031-002724EE 
session 2918: DID 0001-0031-002724EE    session 1432: DID 0001-0017-015A7B2A 

Rows waited on:
  Session 1432: obj - rowid = 00004061 - AAAEBhAAEABfFCsAAA
  (dictionary objn - 16481, file - 4, block - 24924332, slot - 0)
  Session 2918: obj - rowid = 00004061 - AAAEBhAAEABfFCsAAA
  (dictionary objn - 16481, file - 4, block - 24924332, slot - 0)
```

On the second snippet of the trace I see only 1 slot (committed and lock released). According to [Interested Transaction List ( ITL ) in Oracle](http://neeraj-dba.blogspot.ru/2012/05/interested-transaction-list-itl-in.html)  "Lck" means no rows locked at all, then I see 2 rows above?

```
 Object id on Block? Y
 seg/obj: 0x4061  csc: 0x00.24a90627  itc: 1  flg: E  typ: 2 - INDEX
     brn: 0  bdba: 0x156a730 ver: 0x01 opc: 0
     inc: 0  exflg: 0

 Itl           Xid                  Uba         Flag  Lck        Scn/Fsc
0x01   0x0006.00a.0000d5fb  0x000556a1.13a8.02  C---    0  scn 0x0000.24a8fa32
Branch block dump
```

Comment: Is your question why you are seeing the 2 rows above or how to avoid it?

Comment: My question is mostly about treating the got trace file. I want to translate it into English.